# Update Where Equivalent in Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of columns in a dataframe that shouldn't be empty.

I want to remove any rows that are empty in any of these columns. My solution would be to iterate through the required columns and set the column 'excluded' to the error message that the user will be shown before excluding them (I will present these to the user in the form of a report at the end of the process)

I'm currently trying something like this:

```
for col in requiredColumns:
    df[pd.isnull(df[col])]['excluded'] = df[pd.isnull(df[col])]['excluded'].apply(lambda x: str(x) + col + ' empty, excluded')
```

but no luck - the columns aren't updated. The filter by itself (to get only the empty rows) works, the update part doesn't seem to be working.

I'm used to SQL:

```
UPDATE df SET e = e & "empty, excluded" WHERE NZ(col, '') = ''
```

Comment: `dropna()` please check

Comment: I don't want to dropna() - I simply want to mark the nas.

Comment: then fillna work for you

Comment: fillna replaces nas - I want to fill a different column. UPDATE WHERE equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to update a panda based on multiple conditions:

You can simply use `.loc`

```
>>> df
      A   B    C
0     2  40  800
1     1  90  600
2     6  80  700
3  1998  70   55
4     1  90  300
5     7  80  700
6     4  20  300
7  1998  20    2
8     7  10  100
9  1998  60    2

>>> df.loc[(df['A'] > 7) & (df['B'] > 69) , 'C'] = 75
```

This will set 'C' = 75 where 'A' > 7 and 'B' > 69

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `numpy` functions to create a column with the desired marker.

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'B': [2, 3, np.nan, 5, 1, 9],
                   'C': [5, 8, 1, 9, np.nan, 7]})

     A    B    C
0  1.0  2.0  5.0
1  NaN  3.0  8.0
2  2.0  NaN  1.0
3  3.0  5.0  9.0
4  4.0  1.0  NaN
5  5.0  9.0  7.0
```

**Solution**

```
df['test'] = np.any(np.isnan(df.values), axis=1)

     A    B    C   test
0  1.0  2.0  5.0  False
1  NaN  3.0  8.0   True
2  2.0  NaN  1.0   True
3  3.0  5.0  9.0  False
4  4.0  1.0  NaN   True
5  5.0  9.0  7.0  False
```

**Explanation**

- `np.isnan` returns a Boolean array corresponding to whether the elements of a `numpy` array are null.
- Use `np.any` or `np.all`, as required, to determine which rows are in scope.
- Use `df.values` to extract underlying `numpy` array from dataframe. For selected columns, you can use `df[['A', 'B']].values`.